# Uniq command in Linux not working properly

Tags: linux, sorting, uniq

I am new to Linux and while I was trying to understand uinq command I encountered this problem
I created a file hello2 using cat command and entered these text in it

```
hello 

hello   
google   
hello
```

then I ran this command

```
sort hello2 | uniq
```

the output

```
google  
hello  
hello
```

so far what I understood about uniq command on that basis the output should be different

```
google  
hello
```

can someone please understand why this happened?

Comment: Examine your text file in a hex editor. Maybe you have some non-visible characters on some of the lines. Also, please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions on Linux utilities so [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) may be more appropriate for the question.

Comment: I suspect one of the `hello` lines has spaces at the end.

Comment: BTW, you can use `sort -u hello2` to do it in one step. But it will have the same problem if the lines aren't exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a space in one of the repeated words so the other hello is still outputted.

You can check on this [article](https://shapeshed.com/unix-uniq/) for a more detailed information regarding uniq.